# How to change rendering order of the components in vueJs?

Tags: vue.js, sorting, dynamic, components, vue-dynamic-components

I want to reorder my child components with a data from api in my parent components. Please take a look at the example below:

Parent component:

```
   <div v-if="data">
    <Component_1 />
    <Component_2 />
    <Component_3 />
    <Component_4 />
  </div>
```

I want to render like this with a data from backend and user can be able to send me a data like wordpress to reorder the components every time that he wants:

Parent component after user change the order data from backend:

```
<div v-if="data">
    <Component_4 />
    <Component_2 />
    <Component_1 />
    <Component_3 />
  </div>
```

Do I have a way to make it done ? or It's impossible in vuejs?

I tried to make dynamics components but i can't to sort them or I don't know!

Comment: How backend will send the order of components? I mean what format?

Comment: Let me explain the problem I will get a data like numbers from graphQL (json)... By this data is it possible to order the components in front-end when they all has been added in parent?

Comment: Can you tell the JSON?

Comment: @NehaSoni what do you mean by tell the JSON?

Comment: I mean your JSON data which you received from the backed response. I added the answer, see if it helps, if JSON data is an array of numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop on the backend response array and use the `:is` attribute to render the components in the array's item order.

Here is a demo-

```js
const Component_1 = Vue.component('Component_1', {
  template: '<div>Component 1</div>'
})
const Component_2 = Vue.component('Component_2', {
  template: '<div>Component 2</div>'
})
const Component_3 = Vue.component('Component_3', {
  template: '<div>Component 3</div>'
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      response: [1, 2, 3]
    }
  },
  components: {
    Component_1,
    Component_2,
    Component_3
  },
  methods: {
    reorder() {
      // Suppose you get the data in numbers from the backend like
      // [1,2,3] or [2,3,1]
      this.response = [2, 3, 1];
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button @click="reorder()">Re-order</button>
  <component :is="`Component_${num}`" v-for="(num, i) in response" :key="i"></component>
</div>
```

Comment: Then how can I add separate props to each component? :v-bind?

Comment: You can create a computed property which will return the prop data that you want to pass according to the current component. For example- `<component :is="currentComponent" :prop_data="getPropData"></component>` and the computed property will be- `computed: { getPropData() { if(this.currentComponent == 'someName' { 
return { // your data } }) } }`

Answer (score 1):

When you have some array of components names in the correct order from the backend:

```
const componentsOrder = ['Component_4', 'Component_1', 'Component_2', 'Component_3'];
```

In the Vue template you can use `<component>` tag with `is` attribute:

```
<div v-if="data">
  <component 
    v-for="componentName in componentsOrder" 
    :key="componentName" 
    :is="componentName" 
  />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can order the numbers, you can use `component` and its prop `is` to render the components dynamically :

```html
<div v-if="data">
  <template v-for="num in orderedNums">
    <component :is="`Component_${num}`"
 </template>
</div>
```